# How can I change the color of the text in webview in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, webview

I have a webview in an activity to show some details. I have dark mode and light mode in my app. How can I control or change the text color in the webview? I didn't try anything because I didn't find any way.

> > 

a clear discription:
I get object form the backend
the object has an attribute called description and it's a string
this discription is containing html code
i pass the string in the web view
how can i control the text font color?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

String text = ""

- "<style type="text/css">body{color: #fff; background-color: #000; }"
- ""
- ""
- your_string_text_here
- "";

webview1.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I get object form the backend 
the object has an attribute called description and it's a string
this discription is containing html code
i pass the string in the web view 
how can i control the text font color?